# xcode Group and filesystem - best practice to match structure for SVN usage?

Tags: xcode, svn

xcode Group and filesystem - best practice to match structure for SVN usage?

Does it matter if the structure doesn't match the filesystem? To me it is a better idea to match the Filesystem structure to allow for easy multiple developer usage when this is used against SVN.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since the Group can be (by default) unstructured with respect to the filesystem, I think it is impractical to try and organize the file system, thus SVN.  The difficulty comes in the "policing" and enforcement of the violations during shared development.  If the IDE created the Group as a folder then I think more discussion would be merited.  Once you organize your project with functional Groups, you can ignore the command line of SVN, and view the elegance in the IDE.  It does make for a flat SVN structure (ugly) but that is invisible.